# Elasticsearch - getting a few documents by a field value from one of them

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have these docs:

```
{
   "ProcessGroup": "MyTestProc",
   "Step": "1",
   "ProcessID": "1a",
   "SomeProperty": "SomeValue"
}


{
   "ProcessGroup": "MyTestProc",
   "Step": "2",
   "ProcessID": "1a",
   "SomeProperty": "SomeValue"
}

{
   "ProcessGroup": "MyTestProc",
   "Step": "3",
   "ProcessID": "1a",
   "SomeProperty": "SomeValue"
}

{
   "ProcessGroup": "MyTestProc",
   "Step": "1",
   "ProcessID": "2b",
   "SomeProperty": "SomeValue"
}

{
   "ProcessGroup": "MyTestProc",
   "Step": "4",
   "ProcessID": "1a",
   "SubjectID": "31582891"
}
```

1. Is it possible to get all documents by `ProcessID = 1a` where `SubjectID = 31582891`  in **ONE** query?

**UPDATE**

First - extract all ProcessIDs where SubjectID = 31582891

Second - get all docs by ProcessIDs extracted.

2. Is it possible to search all docs which `SubjectID contains 828`?

Comment: By "extracted" do  you mean without ProcessIDs?

Comment: I search the relevant ProcessID (or ids) that match the SubjectID = 31582891.
Afterwards, I need all docs that match those ProcessID (or ids).

In this case:
For SubjectID = 31582891 I get a single ProcessID which is 1a.
Now I need to get all docs for ProcessID = 1a.

Comment: No, you can't do it in one query. You need two queries.